# docker [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.svc.yyyyyy.com; Unknown error" (docker can't access internet from vpn(anyconnect))

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.10

I am running docker in ubuntu 20.10 from inside vpn for a running a java project (building with maven), but after some time I get this error, is it related to vpn or anything else?, I have checked that docker is successfully installed on system. Do I need to edit any of the system files to run this properly ?

```
aaaaaaa@bbbbbbb-MS-7C79:~/Project/docker$ sudo ./docker-run.sh 
Building xxxxxx-redis
Step 1/4 : FROM xxxxxx.yyyyyy.com/docker-virtual/redis:5
 ---> 68ac78a2f5b6
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER Abcde R&D
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3fca3767ef3b
Step 3/4 : COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b46001ae8867
Step 4/4 : CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e51ba988b1fc
Successfully built e51ba988b1fc
Successfully tagged docker_xxxxxx-redis:latest
Building xxxxxx-av-gateway
Step 1/11 : FROM xxxxxx.yyyyyy.com/docker-virtual/centos:7
 ---> 8652b9f0cb4c
Step 2/11 : MAINTAINER Abcde R&D
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0631b4be5909
Step 3/11 : ADD xxxxxx.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5a0d9bffeebd
Step 4/11 : RUN yum install -y epel-release
 ---> Running in 768276ed9519
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * extras: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * updates: centos.mirror.snu.edu.in
https://repo.svc.yyyyyy.com/yum/xxxxxx-rnd/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.svc.yyyyyy.com; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (xxxxxx),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=xxxxxx ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable xxxxxx
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=xxxxxx

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=xxxxxx.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from xxxxxx: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://repo.svc.yyyyyy.com/yum/xxxxxx-rnd/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: repo.svc.yyyyyy.com; Unknown error"
ERROR: Service 'xxxxxx-av-gateway' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y epel-release' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: could you access `https://repo.svc.yyyyyy.com` in your local machine successfully? @chunky

Comment: yes that I have checked with: ```ping repo.svc.yyyyyy.com```
this is the output:
```PING repo.svc.yyyyyy.com (10.155.20.133) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from repo1.svc.yyyyyy.com (10.155.20.133): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=306 ms
64 bytes from repo1.svc.yyyyyy.com (10.155.20.133): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=637 ms
64 bytes from repo1.svc.yyyyyy.com (10.155.20.133): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=662 ms
...
...
```

Comment: try: `curl https://repo.svc.yyyyyy.com/yum/xxxxxx-rnd/repodata/repomd.xml` , could succefully get text content?@chunky

Comment: I am getting this as output:: ```curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: EE certificate key too weak
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: so fix this problem first could solve your problem or change another repo address. @chunky

Comment: Now ```curl https://repo.svc.yyyyyy.com/yum/xxxxxx-rnd/repodata/repomd.xml``` is working now but problem persists. @Dolphin

Comment: if other repo contain the image, tried other repo address. the problem still remain make me confuse too, tried the tips of the command output. @chunky

Answer (score 0):

This problem resolved after I installed OpenConnect SSL VPN client ([from this link](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-openconnect-ssl-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-04/)) and used this instead of anyconnect, Now docker runs successfully, now even if I run docker with anyconnect, it runs fine.